# Subconsulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subconsultas

Buenos días por favor su ayuda,

Quiero hacer una consulta.
Tengo unos estados, A, N y C, y quiero que la consulta me traiga esos estados. Hasta ahí no hay problema.

El problema es que cuando el estado sea C, solo quiero dejar aquellos contratos donde el tipo de cancelacion sean 1 y 12.
Me explico:  Cuando hay un cambio en el estado de un contrato por ejemplo de A (Activo) a C (Cancelado), se genera una novedad en la tabla novedad, la cual contiene un campo que se llama concepto codigo concepto. Y de la tabla concepto hay varios conceptos de los cuales solo quiero tomar 1 y 12 cuando la novedad sea C (Cancelado)
En resumen quiero tomar "todos los estados" A y N y cuando sea C sólo tomar si el codigo concepto sea 1 o 12.

Tengo la siguiente consula pero me arroja error. Agradezco algo de apoyo.

```
SELECT
c.nro_contrato,
u.cc_contratante,
u.persona_cc,
c.fecha_venta,
u.estado,
u.clase_usuario,
u.ejecutivo_comercial_codigo_ejecutivo,
ej.ciudad_cod_ciudad
FROM
contrato AS c
JOIN usuario AS u ON
u.cc_contratante = c.persona_cc
AND u.contrato_nro_contrato = c.nro_contrato
JOIN ejecutivo_comercial AS ej ON
ej.codigo_ejecutivo = u.ejecutivo_comercial_codigo_ejecutivo
JOIN novedad AS n ON
n.contrato_nro_contrato = c.nro_contrato
AND ej.ciudad_cod_ciudad = u.ciudad_cod_ciudad
WHERE
ej.ciudad_cod_ciudad = '01'
AND c.fecha_venta BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-05'
AND u.estado IN ('A', 'M', 'C')
AND u.clase_usuario IN ('A', 'N', 'RV') /*Aqui filtro para que del 
estado C solo me traiga los codigos 1 y 12*/ /*La tabla estado no se 
relaciona con la tabla novedad, solo que cuando un estado es C o 
cancelado, se crea un codigo de tipo de cancelacion*/ 
WHERE n.concepto_cod_concepto IN (SELECT concepto_cod_contepto FROM 
novedad WHERE IN (1, 12));
```

Aquí un ejemplo de la consulta; Los estados C no quisiera que salgan los cod tachados con X o mejor, solo se admiten los codigos 1 y 12.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por favor su ayuda. Espero haberme dado a entender.

Comment: en cual tabla esta cancelación; esa clausula debes meterla en una subconsulta dentro del JOIN .

Comment: mira el IF va en la sub consulta  ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/5951204/17161735

Comment: puedes adjuntar un ejemplo de tu estructura y datos, mínima de esas 3 tablas y dar un ejemplo de lo que esperas????

Comment: tambien el IF puedes meterlo en el where: https://electrictoolbox.com/mysql-using-if-in-where/

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent ya subí el resultado de la consulta sin el filtro que quiero hacer. Gracias por tu interés.

Comment: no uses imágenes cuando te pidan una muestra de datos sube en un texto lo que tienes

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent El texto ya lo subí, el texto de la imagen es el mismo, solo que en la imagen no está el último where.

Comment: no uses imágenes ... usa texto como haces con el código.

Comment: Es complicado poder ayudarte si no agregas la estructura de tu base de datos, las imágenes no ayudan mucho.